# Size of region capture is smaller than screen resolution

Tags: greenshot

When I capture (either a region or window) with Greenshot and opt to send it to MS Paint, the resulting image is noticeably smaller than the screen from which I captured.

As an example, I will include here two images that showcase the problem.

Here is a capture, made with Greenshot, showing in paint. I can already see that (at 100% zoom) it is smaller than the actual display I grabbed.
[image]

To showcase that, I will capture *the image above* with Greenshot. Here it is:

[image]

Notice how it has shrunk in comparison to the previous capture. Sorry if this is confusing, but it's the only way I could quickly come up with to show that Greenshot is reducing the captured content!

I've tried looking at the options and settings but couldn't find anything that relates to this; and only questions about *reducing* rather than increasing the resulting screengrab online.

Appreciate any insights on this, as otherwise Greenshot is an awesome piece of software.

Comment: Zoom level on one or other of the apps is different, or one is using HiDPI settings & the other isn't.

Comment: Hi, Tetsujin. I appreciate the help. The zoom level on the browser from which I captured doesn't matter, right? And paint is at 100% zoom in both instances above. About HiDPI - 'm not knowleadgeable about this, will look into it. If you have any useful links please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Ah - Tetsujin pointed me towards the correct keyword for searching. I found this question, which seems to be what is causing the issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1198359/how-to-take-screenshot-at-100-size-on-a-high-dpi-with-scaling-enabled

Comment: Glad you found the link. tbh, I don't use Windows enough to know how to fix this, I only know it's a common problem. Windows seems to handle HiDPI very badly.